# Error while installing Sitecore 10 using SIA

Tags: sia

Trying to install Sitecore 10 using SIA (as I'm having issues with the container installation getting started template).  I'm following this blog post:
http://madhuanbalagan.com/installing-sitecore-10-using-sia

[image]

Detailed error message is:

```
[-------------- XConnectXP0_InstallWDP : WebDeploy ---------------------------]
[WebDeploy]:[Path] C:\Program Files\iis\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe
Error Code: ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE
More Information: An error occurred during execution of the database script. The error occurred between the following lines of the script: "10" and "18". The verbose log might have more information about the error. The command started with the following:

"DECLARE @containmentLevel tinyint = CONVERT(tiny"
 Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178587  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE.

Error: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Error: The wait operation timed out

Error count: 1.
```

Unfortunately, the link takes me to the Microsoft site with very little information.  This is the second time I have gotten this error.  The first time it actually created the Sitecore 10 databases as I had to delete them before I could run the installation again.  This time however no databases but it has verified that the credentials supplied for the local SQL server worked ok.

Confirming validation passed relating to connection to SQL server.
[image]

Rerunning installation gives me:
[image]

Update: So now that I've upgraded my SQL server I'm getting a new error:
[image]

Why would it be looking in this folder given that it wasn't related at all to the location or service name specified?

[image]

Even after stopping my other solr service - it's still looking in this location.

Here's the folder specified on the solr settings screen:
[image]

Here is the referenced service pointing to that folder:
[image]

Comment: Is the correct instance of SQL server used? Either the path is incorrect or incompatible version?

Comment: Initially it had the wrong path for sql, so when it validated the connection to SQL it failed, but I fixed that and validation passed and it seemed ok.  I would have thought sql2016 would be compatible.  In a previous attempt it did create all the databases but still had the above error

Comment: Looks like 2017 is the minimum requirement. There may be a technical reason for it so may be worth upgrading sooner than later. https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - have fallen into the trap of corporate laptop and sticking to the project specific sql versions.  Will try upgrading and re-installing. Shame the validation doesn't check that if that is indeed the case.

Comment: @MichaelWest Got over my sql hurdle but now it seems to be creating solr cores whilst ignoring the solr values I provided as part of the install.  Nothing obvious jumps out in the json files but it seems to be grabbing the path from my "solr" service which is older (even if I stop it)

Comment: From the SOLR error logs screenshot, : this basically occurs due to incorrect SOLR root path (the path must contain the bin, server folders etc., ) .. Make sure you have a working SOLR service and then enter the relevant details in the SOLR settings step. SOLR step can be got over easily.

Comment: @PaulsonMaclean It auto populated the path and service name after installing a new version.   Even skipping over the installation step and entering in the service name and path - what is shown on the solr settings screen is not what the installer is using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like two things tripped me up:

- Not having the right version of SQL server (2017 minimum)
- Something went wrong with the creation of the solr service using the installer - even though it looked like it had installed/was running ok.  Manually setting up the service and referencing that in the installer worked like a charm.

For anyone needing a reminder on how to install solr with SSL using nssm you can follow:
https://medium.com/redhotminute-australia/setting-up-solr-with-ssl-for-sitecore-9-acdf009edd93